# Cannot draw routes on MapControl (Windows Phone 8.1)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I need to draw a driving route between two points on my MapControl (I'm doing this for Windows Phone 8.1). I did everything with the MSDN's tutorial but it doesn't work - the route is empty. What am I doing wrong? Here's the code.

```
BasicGeoposition startLocation = new BasicGeoposition();
startLocation.Latitude = 40.7517;
startLocation.Longitude = -073.9766;
Geopoint startPoint = new Geopoint(startLocation);

// End at Central Park in New York City.
BasicGeoposition endLocation = new BasicGeoposition();
endLocation.Latitude = 40.7669;
endLocation.Longitude = -073.9790;
Geopoint endPoint = new Geopoint(endLocation);

// Get the route between the points.
MapRouteFinderResult routeResult =
    await MapRouteFinder.GetDrivingRouteAsync(
    startPoint,
    endPoint,
    MapRouteOptimization.Time,
    MapRouteRestrictions.None,
    290
    );


MapRouteView viewOfRoute = new MapRouteView(routeResult.Route);
viewOfRoute.RouteColor = Colors.Blue;
viewOfRoute.OutlineColor = Colors.Blue;

// Add the new MapRouteView to the Routes collection
// of the MapControl.
mapeczka.Routes.Add(viewOfRoute);

// Fit the MapControl to the route.
await mapeczka.TrySetViewBoundsAsync(
    routeResult.Route.BoundingBox,
    null,
    Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps.MapAnimationKind.Bow);

if (routeResult.Status == MapRouteFinderStatus.Success)
{
    // Use the route to initialize a MapRouteView.
    viewOfRoute = new MapRouteView(routeResult.Route);
    viewOfRoute.RouteColor = Colors.Yellow;
    viewOfRoute.OutlineColor = Colors.Black;

    // Add the new MapRouteView to the Routes collection
    // of the MapControl.

}
mapeczka.Routes.Add(viewOfRoute);
// Fit the MapControl to the route.
await mapeczka.TrySetViewBoundsAsync(
    routeResult.Route.BoundingBox,
    null,
    Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps.MapAnimationKind.None);
```

Comment: Could you be more Specific ? I think you are using some third party library for this.

Comment: I tried your code and it works perfectly for me. Have you set the ApplicationID and AuthenticationToken properly? Also I see some redundancy in your code (the last part is duplicate of code above it).

Comment: Thanks, it was it. I'm completely new to Windows Phone but I'm learning :) Fortunately I didn't have to pay for the token - I got mine from my Dreamspark account :)

Comment: I have the same problem. No route is displayed on the map, and I have a token. Where is the problem exactly. I use the same code..

Comment: I did everything according to this tutorial. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn741528.aspx - Don't forget to edit your package.appxmanifest file.